# CSS inline-block

Tags: html, css, display

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXdrT.png)

I am trying to practice CSS and display : inline-block doesn' work for me 
I learned inline-block act just as float : left but it doesn't.
I want red and blue bordered div to be in same line.

```
        #align {
            border : 1px solid yellow;
            width : 100%;
            height : 80vmin;
            vertical-align: 0; 
        }
        #align div{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        #align #search{
            width : 300px;
            height : 300px;
            border : 1px solid red;
            margin : 0;
        }

        #align #image{
            width : 300px;
            height : 300px;
            border : 1px solid blue;
            margin : 0;
        }
 <body>
    <div id = "logo">
        <h1>Word Count!</h1>
    </div>
    <div id = "align">
        <div id = "search">
            <form action="{% url 'count'%}">
                <textarea name='textarea'>write things down!</textarea> 
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Count!">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id = "image">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I fix my problem?

Comment: Can you please add your html code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex;` (in your case `#align`)  to wrap element instead `inline-block` to children

```css
#align {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vmin;
  vertical-align: 0;
  display: flex;
}


#align #search {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
}

#align #image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="logo">
    <h1>Word Count!</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="align">
    <div id="search">
      <form action="{% url 'count'%}">
        <textarea name='textarea'>write things down!</textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Count!">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="image">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```